# PHP MySQL SELECT from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

```
players
bans
```

And I have mysql queries:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare( "SELECT ban_Type, ban_Reason FROM bans WHERE ban_Name = ? LIMIT 1" );
$stmt->execute( array( $_SESSION['admin_session'] ) );
```

And I want to get ID row from another table..

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM players WHERE Name = ? LIMIT 1" );
$stmt->execute( array( $_SESSION['admin_session'] ) );
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should look into mysql's `JOIN` syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: It'd be nice to see what it was that you tried, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. Post something that may have failed, even that shows an effort on your part and we're always glad to help :-)

Comment: @jeroen *Yep!* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to do without knowing your database structure, but basically this should work:

```
SELECT b.ban_Type
     , b.ban_Reason
     , p.Name
FROM bans b
    JOIN players p ON p.ID = b.players_ID
WHERE ban_Name = ?
LIMIT 1
```